# Dynamically store and access file via url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, facebook, file, jsf

I am trying to generate a feed file to publish to Facebook. They require a URL to hit and grab a file. I was wondering what approach I should take to store and make the file publicly available to Facebook.

My first approach was to store the CSV file in a public folder named "feed" located in webapp/feed/{filename.csv}, however, I have come to learn that using `Faces.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")` is not the best approach as the files are lost on redeployment or server restart. This approach seems to only work on my local environment, and not AWS.

My next approach was to store each users individual feed files in my database and retrieve them on request, but I have not been able to find information on if/how this is possible. I am not confused on how to get the file, but how to design a page that makes it available to Facebook to retrieve.

In short, I want to take a CSV file I have created and make it publicly available through a URL that Facebook can identify and grab. Currently, I am looking at Amazon Elastic File System to solve this problem. Is this the correct approach or is there a simpler solution.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Facebook feeds, but typically if you need to provide a file you would provide an endpoint that accepts the filename as input (e.g. https://www.myapp.com/facebook-feed-endpoint-example/FeedFile12345678.csv where FeedFile12345678.csv is an input parameter on your endpoint), then you change the Content-Type on the response object to be "text/csv".

Comment: I actually made a solution very similar to this but much simpler. I’ll post the update at a later time. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer grabs a feed file from a specific users database. Feed files are just a CSV file containing product information with values required by Facebook. When a data feed is scheduled with Facebook, they hit a given url (for example, [https://www.yourwebsite.com/feed.xhtml?user={some_user}](https://www.yourwebsite.com/feed.xhtml?user=%7Bsome_user%7D)). This url should send a file to the requester. This xhtml file and java class do exactly that. Keep in mind, this example does not show how the files are generated only how they are returned.

**feed.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:adm="http://github.com/adminfaces">
    
    <h:body>
        <!-- Meta Data -->
        <f:metadata>

            <f:viewParam name="user" value="#{feed.userId}"
                converter="javax.faces.Long" />
            
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{feed.init}" />

        </f:metadata>
    
    </h:body>
    
</html>
```

**Feed.java**

```
package me.walkerworks.bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;
import me.walkerworks.security.DataConnect;


/**
 * 
 * @author Thomas Walker 6/18/2020
 *
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Feed implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userId;
    
    private int feedId;
    private byte[] content;

    /**
     * Initialized Bean
     * 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void init() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

        if (userId != null) {

            // Connection var
            Connection connection = null;

            // Loading jdbc driver for mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            // Getting connection from products table
            connection = DataConnect.getConnection("user" + userId);

            // Prepare Statement
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection

                    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM feeds");

            // Execute statement and get result
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // If there is data to load from db
            if (resultSet.next()) {

                // Set feed id
                feedId = resultSet.getInt("id");
                

                // Get and store the file in class
                if (resultSet.getBytes("content") != null) {

                    // Get long blob 
                    content = resultSet.getBytes("content");

                }
            }

            // Closing connections
            resultSet.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            DataConnect.close(connection);
            
            // If content isn't null
            if (content != null) {
                
                // Send file
                Faces.sendFile(content, feedId + ".csv", true);
                
            }           
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the feedId
     */
    public int getFeedId() {
        return feedId;
    }

    /**
     * @param feedId the feedId to set
     */
    public void setFeedId(int feedId) {
        this.feedId = feedId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * @param content the content to set
     */
    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code only is not the best way of answering. Please add some explanation on the most important changes/things

Comment: I edited the answer and provided an explanation. There were no changes made, this was made from scratch.